# What is C#'s version of the GIL?

Tags: c#, java, python, gil

In the current implementation of CPython, there is an object known as the "GIL" or "Global Interpreter Lock". It is essentially a mutex that prevents two Python threads from executing Python code at the same time. This prevents two threads from being able to corrupt the state of the Python interpreter, but also prevents multiple threads from really executing together. Essentially, if I do this:

```
# Thread A
some_list.append(3)
# Thread B
some_list.append(4)
```

I can't corrupt the list, because at any given time, only one of those threads are executing, since they must hold the GIL to do so. Now, the items in the list might be added in some indeterminate order, but the point is that the list isn't corrupted, and two things will always get added.

So, now to C#. C# essentially faces the same problem as Python, so, how does C# prevent this? I'd also be interested in hearing Java's story, if anyone knows it.

---

**Clarification:** I'm interested in what happens without explicit locking statements, especially to the VM. I am aware that locking primitives exist for both Java & C# - they exist in Python as well: The GIL is not used for multi-threaded code, other than to keep the interpreter sane. I am interested in the direct equivalent of the above, so, in C#, if I can remember enough... :-)

```
List<String> s;
// Reference to s is shared by two threads, which both execute this:
s.Add("hello");
// State of s?
// State of the VM? (And if sane, how so?)
```

Here's another example:

```
class A
{
    public String s;
}
// Thread A & B
some_A.s = some_other_value;

// some_A's state must change: how does it change?
// Is the VM still in good shape afterwards?
```

I'm not looking to write bad C# code, I understand the `lock` statements. Even in Python, the GIL doesn't give you magic-multi-threaded code: you must still lock shared resources. But the GIL prevents Python's "VM" from being corrupted - it is this behavior that I'm interested in.

Comment: You may be interested in the "Concurrency" section of this [comparison of Python and Clojure](http://www.bestinclass.dk/index.clj/2009/10/python-vs-clojure-evolving.html), for a discussion of the GIL and how the problem of concurrency is handled in languages without a GIL.

Comment: My understanding is that it is a trade off between what class of problems will be more burdensome to solve. See my answer below.

Answer (score 12):

Most other languages that support threading don't have an equivalent of the Python GIL; they require you to use mutexes, either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Furthermore, I would never even consider writing multi-threaded code in a language with anything like a GIL. It's like a flashing neon sign that says, "Multithreading is too hard; we give up."

Comment: I wouldn't consider writing a multithread program in a language that can't keep its basic data structure consistent by itself and relies on programmers to add locks everywhere.

Comment: You'd rather use a language in which it's impossible for more than one thing to happen at a time? That's not a multithreaded program. And no, "adding locks everywhere" is not the only alternative.

Comment: @Joel Mueller: So, without a GIL, what do you use to keep the internal state of the interpreter or VM sane, and prevent errors from multiple threads trying to alter the state of the VM?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "state of the VM"? The only state that matters is the state of the particular objects being manipulated by multiple threads. If the VM needs to do a garbage-collection, it pauses all threads until the GC is done. The VM can't be corrupted by multiple threads messing with an object instance - only that object's data can be corrupted. Putting locks only where you need to, rather than having an implicit lock on absolutely everything, allows for dramatically better performance.

Comment: @JoelMueller: Where in the Python *language* does it specify a GIL?

Comment: @Nick - My mistake. I gather there are some Python implementations without a GIL, which is great. I should have said _environment_ rather than _language_. But by the same token, the OP could have just as well asked his question about other Python interpreters as C#.

Answer (score 4):

Using lock, you would do this:

```
lock(some_list)
{
    some_list.Add(3);
}
```

and in thread 2:

```
lock(some_list)
{
    some_list.Add(4);
}
```

The `lock` statement ensures that the object inside the `lock` statement, `some_list` in this case, can only be accessed by a single thread at a time. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx for more information.

Comment: I could, and Python has similar lock statements. I'm more interested in the case that the locks are not done: is it possible to corrupt the underlying VM?

Comment: @Thanatos: Not the VM, but the data structure.

Comment: The result is that there will be no guarantee what will happen. It will **not** corrupt the state of the VM. It may however corrupt the state of the instance you are calling the methods on. When not specifically noted in the MSDN pages, the general rule is that instance methods must be enclosed in `lock`'s and static methods do not have to be enclosed in `lock`'s.

Comment: lock does not ensure the object inside the lock statement can only be accessed by a single thread. It marks a code block as a critical section and ensures no other threads enter that critical section. You could modify the list outside of the lock. I would change your description of the lock statement.

Comment: @Pieter: What mechanism does the VM use to remain in a sane state?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You must enclose calls to that object in **all** threads that access the instance. The link to the MSDN page explains this perfectly :).

Comment: @Thanatos - I don't know. What I do know is that there is no interference between the 'user' code and the internal VM state. This is not something you have to worry about with C#.

Comment: @Thanatos what VM state are you talking about? In C# almost everything is done per thread. Threads even have their own heap to allocate memory.

Comment: @stonemetal - The VM does have state. For example garbage collection is something internal to the VM that the VM actually manages. It e.g. needs to keep threads from running during specific phases of the collection and yes, it has state and yes, there is synchronization there. The assumption is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

C# does not have an equivalent of GIL to Python.

> Though they face the same issue, their design goals make them
>   different.
>
> **With GIL, CPython** ensures that suche operations as appending a list
>   from two threads is simple. Which also
>   means that it would allow only one
>   thread to run at any time. This
>   **makes lists and dictionaries thread safe**. Though **this makes the job
>   simpler and intuitive**, it makes it
>   harder to exploit the multithreading
>   advantage on multicores.
>
> **With no GIL, C#** does the opposite. **It ensures that the burden of integrity is on the developer of the
>   program** but allows you to take
>   advantage of running multiple threads
>   simultaneously.

As per one of the discussion -

> The GIL in CPython is purely a design choice of having 
>      a big lock vs a lock per object
>      and synchronisation to make sure that objects are kept in a coherent state.
>      This consist of a trade off - Giving up the full power of
>   multithreading.
>
> It has been that most problems do not suffer from this disadvantage 
>      and there are libraries which help you exclusively solve this issue when
>   required. 
>       That means for a certain class of problems, the burden to utilize the
>   multicore is 
>       passed to developer so that rest can enjoy the more simpler, intuitive
>   approach.

Note: Other implementation like IronPython do not have GIL.

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: Thank a lot. Somehow the quote is not working for me when I select a text and try to quote it.

Comment: Strange, well the secret is that it's just `> ` at the beginning of a line that forces the blockquote instead of code formatting.  Note that you can still do code formatting as well within a block quote by spacing it appropriately with a `> ` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

It may be instructive to look at the [documentation for the Java equivalent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html) of the class you're discussing:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access an `ArrayList` instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
> ```
>
> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

Answer (score 0):

Most complex datastructures(for example lists) can be corrupted when used without locking in multiple threads.

Since changes of references are atomic, a reference always stays a valid reference.

But there is a problem when interacting with security critical code. So any datastructures used by critical code most be one of the following:

- Inaccessible from untrusted code, and locked/used correctly by trusted code
- Immutable (String class)
- Copied before use (valuetype parameters)
- Written in trusted code and uses internal locking to guarantee a safe state

For example critical code cannot trust a list accessible from untrusted code. If it gets passed in a List, it has to create a private copy, do it's precondition checks on the copy, and then operate on the copy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess at what the question *really* means...

In Python data structures in the interpreter get corrupted because Python is using a form of reference counting.

Both C# and Java use garbage collection and in fact they **do** use a global lock when doing a full heap collection.

Data can be marked and moved between "generations" without a lock. But to actually clean it up everything must come to a stop. Hopefully a very short stop, but a full stop.

Here is an interesting link on CLR garbage collection as of 2007:
http://vineetgupta.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!8DE4BDC896BEE1AD!1104.entry